# SQL only join if conditions are met

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a site where users can share content.

I have a table called "Posts" with two columns; `"Type"` and `"Media"`. The `"Type"` column identifies what kind of post it is. i.e. if it contains any photos or if it's just a plain post. If it contains a photo the `"Type"` column will have the value `"b"` and if it's a blank post with no photo it will have the value `"a"`. If the value of `"Type"` is equal to `"b"` the `"Media"` column will have an ID integer as the value identifies the photo attached to the post.

In a separate table, `"Photos"` each photo that is uploaded is given a unique ID. This unique ID is put into the value of `"Media`" in the `"Posts"` table.

I want to do an `INNER JOIN` in my `SQL` syntax **ONLY** if the value of `"Type"` is equal to `"b"`.

Can anyone help point me in the correct direction?

Comment: This is way too wordy.  But just add `Where Type = 'b'`.

Comment: But then when it won't return any posts that have the `type=a`

Comment: Ah, I see - in that case, you need `Left Join` with a second `On` clause for `Type = 'b'`

Comment: The question I have is "why". If there is a proper foreign key relationship, the photo must always exist if there is an `id` in media, so you don't even need to check the type (and therefor, the `type` column is obsolete). Also, I'd recommend storing the PostId with a picture instead of vice versa, or even cerate a junction table, otherwise a post can have only one picture, which seems limiting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you really want to do a `Left Join`.  A `Left Join` will give you the data if it exists, but otherwise, will show null data for photos.

Maybe something like this:

```
Select *
From Posts
   Left Join Photos on Posts.MEDIA = Photos.MEDIA 
                    and Photos.Type = 'b'
```

If this was just text, it'd look like:

```
Type    Media    Photo
a       w/e
b       w/e      cats.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way, as suggested by Philip, is to use an Outer Join, but if you really want to avoid an outer Join, you need to use a subquery...

```
 SELECT Type,
    (Select case when p.type = 'p' 
            then photo [or whatever column you want] else null end 
     from Photos where id = p.Media) photo
 FROM posts p
```

Comment: Ah, this is actually a really nice method.  I use subqueries in Select statements quite often, especially when it's just for output, and not to be used as criteria.  Easier to reuse as well (at least in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

You can have several conditions in the `join` statement:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       posts
INNER JOIN photos ON posts.media = photos.id AND 
           posts.type = 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `left join`; something like below

```
select * from posts p
left join photos pp on p.media = pp.media
and p.type = 'b'
```